# How do we highlight or change the color of a button after it is pressed in swift Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I am having a problem in Swift. I want to change the color of a button when I press it. I am actually making a Quiz in which there are four options and I want to change the color to red if the answer is wrong or change the color to green if the answer is correct. Can somebody help me out with this please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use bool for that like shown below:

```
var currectAnswer = Bool()
```

change this `Boolean` into another function if answer is correct set it as true and if answer is wrong then set it to false.

After that you can set this action for that button:

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    if currectAnswer {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    } else if !currectAnswer {
        sender.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
}
```

Hope It will help.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the color of the button text,you could try this way:

```
yourButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
```

If you want to change the background color of the button,try this code:

```
yourButton.backgroundColor = .greenColor()
```